# Fetching geo data from google API while creating new record on DB

Tags: mysql, web-services, google-api

I have an entity that one of it's members is the actual city, country that it was "created" - the user only gives me lat, long coordinates and I need to use the google API to reverse geocode the coordinates into city, country.

My question - What is the best way to fetch that information? is it safe enough to use a 3rd party web service in the middle of a record creating process? What are the common ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly safe enough. The only issue is response time (as you will be calling the remote web service synchronously), but if you're doing this once only on each insert I don't think that would be much of a problem.

The Google Geocoding API [will return results in XML format](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#XML), so you just need to call the web service URL and pull the information you need from the response.

Here's an example reverse geocoding result:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

You don't say which language you're using, but I'm assuming PHP—here's a very basic example of parsing the response and displaying the addresses using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$lat = 40.714224;
$lng = -73.961452;

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" . $lat . "," . $lng . "&sensor=false");

foreach($xml->result as $result)
{
    foreach($result->address_component as $addresscomponent)
    {
        echo $addresscomponent->long_name . ' ';
    }

    echo '<br />';
}
```